# Proving isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Perhaps a trivial question, but I want certainty.

> Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups, generated by respectively $S \subset G$ and $R \subset H$. Suppose we have an group homomorphism $\phi:  G \to H$. If we have proven that:
>
> - $\phi(x)=\phi(y) \implies  x=y\forall x,y \in S$ 
>     and
> - $\forall y \in R$, $\exists x \in S$ such that $\phi(x)=y$

Can we conclude that $\phi$ is  a bijection or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**.

Define $\phi:\Bbb Z_4\to \Bbb Z_2$

by $\phi([1])=[1]$
where $S=T=\{[1]\}$

**EDITS**:

*$G$ is finite*:

Note that if $G=H,S=T$ then for each $h\in H$ we have $h=g_1^{k_1}g_2^{k_2}\cdots g_n^{k_n}$ where $S=T=\{g_1,g_2,\ldots ,g_n\}$ is a set of generators of $G=H$.

Then for each $g_i,\exists g_i^{'}\in S$ where $g_i^{'}$ is $g_i$ for some $1\le i\le n$ such that $\phi(g_i^{'})=g_i$  where $\phi :G\to H$ is the required homomorphism.

Hence we have $h=\phi(g_1^{'}g_2^{'}\cdots g_n^{'})^{k_1}$ so the mapping is surjective

Since the group is finite and $G=H$ we have $\phi $ is injective as well and so bijective.

*$G$ is infinite*:

Consider $\mathbb Q[x]$ the set of all polynomials over $\Bbb Q$ and take $S= \{1,x,x^2,\ldots ,x^n,\ldots\}$.

Also take $T(f(x))=f^{'}(x)$ which is a homomorphism satisfying conditions $1,2$ of yours but is not bijective .

Comment: Okay, but when $H=G$ and $S=R$ it does hold, right?

Comment: @J.Bosser; Added required elements

Comment: what about if $G$ is infinite?

Comment: @J.Bosser;You can check the edited edits

Comment: @J.Bosser; Please accept the answer if it served you